# Apply Angular date filter to 'MMMM' in ng-options select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my question. I've written a drop-down select that shows months by numbers. I would like to apply a filter to the drop-down so that it displays the numbers as full month names.

Here is the initial code:

```
<select ng-model="month" ng-options="month as month for month in months" ng-change="updateMonth()">
<option value="">Choose Month</option>
</select>
```

I added this, experimenting, and surprisingly it did something, but not what I wanted... it changed the name of every select option in the list to December - the app still functions properly but it isn't showing all the different names:

```
<select ng-model="month" ng-options="month as month | date: 'MMMM' for month in months" ng-change="updateMonth()">
<option value="">Choose Month</option>
</select>
```

The js 'months' is just an array from 0-11 of the month numbers.

**To clarify**

The initial display in the dropdown select for months is this:

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11

With the filter I wrote in there, this is what displays:

December
December
December
December
December
December
December
December
December
December
December

Answer (score 1):

when angular filter *date* receives an integer as in your case, it is considered to be a timestamp (milliseconds), milliseconds from 0 to 11 belongs to the same month, that is why your result is 12 same month names.
To solve it create an array of timestamps for 12 month of the current year:

```
let d = new Date();
// create array of timestamps for 12 month of thr current year
$scope.months = Array.apply(null, Array(12)).map((v, k) => d.setMonth(k));
```

now in HTML:

```
<select ng-model="month" 
        ng-options="month as timestamp | date: 'MMMM' for (month, timestamp) in months" 
        ng-change="updateMonth()">
  <option value="">Choose Month</option>
</select>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dhAoiRUHzLPlskh1iwKq?p=preview

Comment: Your solution works flawlessly. I just need to learn how it works now! .

Comment: Array.apply(null, Array(12)) creates an array of integers: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]. Than, Array.map() along with Date.setMonth() functions convert this array into array of 12 time stamps (time stamp is a number of millseconds since January 1970), each item in this array represents the beginning of each month of the current year. Than, each of these time stamps is processed by angular date filter |(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) in HTML template.  I used "(month, timestamp) in months" so name displayed will be month name but value sent to ng-model will be month number (0-11)

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be useful for someone, my decision:

```
 <select (change)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(12); let j = index;" value="{{j}}"
          [selected]="j+1 == currentMonth.numberOfMonth">
  {{currentMonth.year + '-' + j==0?12:j+1 + '-' + 01|date:'MMMM'}}
  </option>
</select>
```